# Adding custom fields to the very bottom of the page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've made a template for specific pages of our website that display similar content, yet are different form the rest of the pages of the website - here's [an example](http://bethelcoachtours.com/tours/new-york/ny-bethel-disney-world-orlando-family-expedition/). I have several custom fields that I use to include all of the items you see in the boxes that float to the left and right.

My problem is, I also have pricing that's included from a custom field - and because I want it at the bottom of the page, it actually appears outside the content to work (see the bottom of my example given above). Is there a way I can call the content and tell it to display these custom fields at after the content is displayed?

Obviously the following doesn't work, but just to give you an idea:

```
<?php the_content(get_post_meta($post->ID, "Pricing_Mexico", true); ?>
```

Additionally, there are actually a lot of custom fields that need to be displayed, so if it were possible to include them in bulk (including the markup which includes divs and what-not) that would be preferred. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter `the_content()` so in your functions file:

```
function contentFilter($content){
    // Output the current content
    echo $content;
    // Output the meta field
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "Pricing_Mexico", true);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'contentFilter');
```

You could echo as many meta fields as you need inside the function.

Comment: A filter does not `echo`, it has to `return`.

Comment: The only reason I `echo`'ed was to add the comments above each line to show what was happening. Admittedly I didn't explain at all that it should be concatenated and returned.